# PHP Read Online Excel File Without Download The File

Tags: php, google-sheets, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am creating a web stock apps.
I want to read this Excel or Google Sheet File in this link:

[Link To Report](https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/Corporate_Actions/New_Info_JSX/Jenis_Informasi/01_Laporan_Keuangan/02_Soft_Copy_Laporan_Keuangan//Laporan%20Keuangan%20Tahun%202020/Audit/AALI/FinancialStatement-2020-Tahunan-AALI.xlsx)

Without need to download the file first.

Is it possible for PHP to read and choose the sheet then read entire row and column in online ?

What library I should use ?

I try to use phpspreadsheet but I cannot make it. Not sure if i do it wrong or not.

Also i try to use Google Sheet API. But in the link i cannot find the google spreadsheet id.

So what is the solution in here to read the excel or google spreadsheet online using php ?

**Update :**

Suggest from @ADyson to use a same header to get the data download by php.

So this is my code :

```
function dfCurl($url){
        $ch     =   curl_init($url);
        $dir            =   '../';
        $fileName       =   basename($url);
        $saveFilePath   =   $dir . $fileName;
        $fp             =   fopen($saveFilePath, 'wb');
        $headers = [
            ':authority: www.idx.co.id',
            ':method: GET',
            ':path: /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/Corporate_Actions/New_Info_JSX/Jenis_Informasi/01_Laporan_Keuangan/02_Soft_Copy_Laporan_Keuangan//Laporan%20Keuangan%20Tahun%202021/TW1/AALI/FinancialStatement-2021-I-AALI.xlsx',
            ':scheme: https',
            'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language: en-AU,en;q=0.9,id-ID;q=0.8,id;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5,ja-JP;q=0.4,ja;q=0.3,en-GB;q=0.2,en-US;q=0.1',
            'cache-control: no-cache',
            'cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1396311216.1625813381; skipFeedback=1; __cf_bm=mF3lXNPMKeLe1xFzY5eKQM1TFN.yz7lxgWMJEYWBcjA-1635412963-0-AUMv9HWMpGhIN6c7eDVT++ok0dYE1NL+PyRJBpNUfZviT8bNS5Zm4UQjAm7gUJad4Qv7h+Q9ak+u/Q18tGDx0pU=',
            'pragma: no-cache',
            'referer: https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/laporan-keuangan-dan-tahunan/',
            'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"',
            'sec-fetch-dest: document',
            'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site: same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user: ?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
            'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        ];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);       
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

And I call using :

```
public function Export() {
        // Initialize a file URL to the variable        
        $url = 'https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/Corporate_Actions/New_Info_JSX/Jenis_Informasi/01_Laporan_Keuangan/02_Soft_Copy_Laporan_Keuangan//Laporan%20Keuangan%20Tahun%202021/TW1/AALI/FinancialStatement-2021-I-AALI.xlsx';               
        dfCurl($url);       
    }
```

But unfortunetly I still cannot download the xlsx file properly.
I just got a 1 kb file and when open the file i got error from excel.

So what is the correct way to download from url using php ?

The link is :

> https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/Corporate_Actions/New_Info_JSX/Jenis_Informasi/01_Laporan_Keuangan/02_Soft_Copy_Laporan_Keuangan//Laporan%20Keuangan%20Tahun%202021/TW1/AALI/FinancialStatement-2021-I-AALI.xlsx

Thank You

Comment: 1st question: Are you the owner of the site www.idx.co.id ?

Comment: You can read the file using php spreadsheet, yes. If you found a problem please post your code and explain the exact issue

Comment: @KenLee no, I am not the owner of the site.

Comment: @ADyson It seem that the link report is a google sheet. But in the link provide I cannot find the "ID" and google sheet API need an ID in order to read the sheet.

Comment: I still don't do a code. Because i want to know if it is possible to grab the entire data without donwload it first.

Comment: Is the data in the sheet publicly licensed? And/or do you have permission to reproduce it on your own site? If not then really the best you can do is provide your users with a link to the Google sheets

Comment: @ADyson this data is for public. This is the site that provide the link : https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/laporan-keuangan-dan-tahunan/

Comment: @ADyson I don't want to provide directly the link. But i want to produce a new report base of the data from the link. So i will create a new report according to my calculation.

Comment: I only suggested providing a link in case you didn't have the necessary copyirght or permission to re-use the data. But if you're saying it's public, then I'll assume you've checked that properly.

Comment: `It seem that the link report is a google sheet.` ...why do you think that? When I click the link it just downloads a normal xlsx file.

Comment: So your PHP should be able to download it using file_get_contents, and then you can use phpspreadsheet to read data from it.

Comment: @ADyson I cannot use file_get_contents to download the file. It return an error  Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. Then I try using Curl. But using Curl only give me 1 Kb size which when I open the file it say not valid. Can you try in your end to use file_get_contents or curl to see what the result in there ?

Comment: I also get a 403. If I had to guess, I would say the site has some checks to see if you're requesting from a browser or not - maybe it checks the user-agent string or something. Look at the network tab in your browser while you're downloading it, and see what headers are sent by your browser in the request. Then make a cURL request which emulates that exactly, it might work better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238643/discussion-between-dennis-liu-and-adyson).

Comment: @ADyson could you post the correct header as answer in here ? Is it a response header or request header i need to copy ? Because it still not working

Comment: It's the request headers obviously. The response header is sent back by the server, so the server won't be checking that. If you still have a problem, update your question with the code you've tried

Comment: @ADyson could you check the question ? I have update the question with code above

Answer (score 1):

Finally I can download using php from that site.

All I want to do is use a curl :

```
 function dfCurl($url){
        $ch     =   curl_init($url);
        $dir            =   '../';
        $fileName       =   basename($url);
        $saveFilePath   =   $dir . $fileName;
        $fp             =   fopen($saveFilePath, 'wb');
        $headers = [
            'authority: www.idx.co.id',
            'method: GET',            
            'scheme: https',
            'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',            
            'cache-control: no-cache',            
            'pragma: no-cache',            
            'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Mobile Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        ];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);       
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);        
        fclose($fp);
        
    }
```

And that's all.